# Why does the OS user has to be same as the database user while connecting to PostgreSQL using md5 authentication?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have configured `md5` authentication for user `foo` by putting the following in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE    DATABASE    USER    ADDRESS    METHOD
local     all         foo                md5
```

When I try to connect (using `psql`) as the Linux user `foo`, `psql` asks for the password and the connection is successful. However, if I run `psql` as some other Linux user, I receive the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "foo"
```

What is the reason for this behavior? I am under the impression that this only necessary if I use the `peer` or `ident` authentication methods.

**Edit:** I am using the command `psql -U foo -W` to connect. When I prefix the command with `sudo -u foo` it works; when I don't it gives the error as mentioned above. Sorry for not mentioning this while posting the original question!

**Edit 2:**

Here are all the un-commented lines from my `pg_hba.conf` in order:

```
# TYPE    DATABASE    USER        ADDRESS        METHOD
local     all         postgres                   peer
local     all         foo                        md5
local     all         all         127.0.0.1/32   md5
local     all         all         ::1/128        md5
```

Comment: It's done for convenience. You can always specify a different user using the `-U` (or `--username`) option.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for pointing this out :) But I'm already doing this! Edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: Can you post all the uncommented lines from your pg_hba.conf in order?

Comment: Clodoaldo Neto's answer solved my problem. However, I've edited the question to add the all the un-commented lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the database it will try to connect to the database with the same name as the Linux user. If you are logged as `bar` and do:

```
psql -U foo -W
```

It will try to log to the `bar` database with the `foo` user. To connect to the `foo` database from the `bar` loggin do:

```
psql -U foo -W foo
```

Answer (score 0):

`psql` defaults to whatever the current user is. Use the `-U` flag to pick the database "role".

Postgres roles and the system users are seperate, although authentication can be configured to work against the system's own (pam/ldap/etc).

Comment: I am already using it! I've edited the question in an attempt to clarify this. Thanks for pointing out :)